# Why does PHP's sem_acquire blocks program execution?

Tags: php, semaphore, shared-memory

I am working on a very large and complex PHP project running on gentoo Linux which obviously has some issues with PHP semaphores. Because of the size and complexity of the project I cannot post the code. I also cannot provide a working example that reproduces the problem. It might be caused by the program's complexity in a non-determic manner.

Here is the issue: The PHP code is trying to write and read to/from shared memory using semaphores. In the case that creates the problem, the following actions are done:

1. At time 006.68 the following code is executed by PHP 4.4.9 to write 5 bytes of data into the shared memory, with `$iVarKey` having the value 2010147023

   ```
   sem_acquire($this->rSemaphore);
   shm_put_var($this->rShm, $iVarKey, $mVar);
   sem_release($this->rSemaphore);
   ```

   This action is ended at time 006.69
2. At time 006.77 the following code is executed by PHP 5.2.10 to read 5 bytes of data from the shared memory, with `$iVarKey` having the value 622679600:

   ```
   sem_acquire($this->rSemaphore);
   $mVar = shm_get_var($this->rShm,$iVarKey);
   sem_release($this->rSemaphore);
   ```

   This action is ended at time 006.78
3. At time 016.01 the following code is executed by PHP 5.2.10 (same lines of code as in #2) to read 5 bytes of data from the shared memory, with `$iVarKey` having the value 2010147023 (same as in #1):

   ```
   sem_acquire($this->rSemaphore);
   $mVar = shm_get_var($this->rShm,$iVarKey);
   sem_release($this->rSemaphore);
   ```

   This action now takes about 2 minutes, although the resource/semaphore with the same `$iVarKey` has been released about 10 seconds earlier. There are no accesses to the shared memory in the meantime, as I have identified EVERY call to `sem_acquire`!

How can it be possible that `sem_acquire` blocks the program execution, although it should not. Maybe it is a bug in the version 4.4.9/5.2.10? Has anyone ever seem something similar? Is there a workaround? Is there something I can do to invest this issue further?

I will really appreciate help with this issue!

**Remarks**:

- If you need additional information, I will try to provide them
- Please no comments and remarks about PHP4 or the parallel use of two PHP versions.
- If people think this question does not belong here, please provide guidance.

Additional information:
 - I have checked every call of `sem_release`, and none of them seem to return a `FALSE`. My problem therefore does not arise from a failing release.
 - When the system is blocking, `ipcs -s` returns the following output, identical to when the system is not blocking

```
    ------ Semaphore Arrays --------
    key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     
    0x000f4240 0          root      666        3         
    0x00000001 32769      root      666        3         
    0x00000000 65538      apache    600        1
```

- The call to `sem_get()` for the blocking semaphore is

  ```
  $this->rSemaphore = sem_get(1000000,1,0666,1);
  ```
- The only call involving `ftok` seem to never gets called.

Comment: Both acquire and release can fail.
Try using

    `if(false===sem_acquire($this->rSemaphore)){throw new Exception("Failed to acquire semaphore");}`

    `if(false===sem_release($this->rSemaphore)){throw new Exception("Failed to release semaphore");}`

Comment: try sem_detach in php version 4.4.9 after sem_release and then fetch data in #3

Comment: The command `sem_detach` does not seem to exist.

Comment: Show us your `sem_get()` and `ftok()`. What says `ipcs -s` while blocking? Are you sure (by using a debugger) that those semaphores are released?

Comment: @Markus: Please see updated question with some additional information. I still need to activate a debugger to check the semaphore releases.

Comment: @Alex I understand that you don't use `ftok()` to generate the key. You should reconsider that to avoid collision.

Comment: @Alex The blocking Semaphore is `0x000f4240`. What happens if you remove it before your blocking script by `ipcrm`? My guess it's a semaphore collision. Do you run your scripts as root?

Comment: @Markus Thanks for the help so far. Can you elaborate the meaning of `key` and `semid` in the `ipcs` output? Also, I don't just have a script creating this problem. I have to run a big piece of code multiple times, as the problem only manifests in about 20% of the cases. Mostly, I do not get the problem when I run the 'script'.

Comment: @Marcus: How can I change the posted code ONLY in order to check for a collision and to remove/change/whatever to avoid such a collision? Or how can I prevent the creation of the blocking IPC in the first place?

Comment: The fact that `ipcs -s` looks identically before means that either another process uses the same key or your code didn't release it. I am just guessing that another process uses the same key (0x000f4240). A good convention to avoid that is using ftok(). But as you said it happens in 20% it's also likely that your code sometimes doesn't reach the `sem_release()`. Your missing error handling is a sign for that. A missed `sem_release()` will eventually released after the resource is freed. Time for having a look into the error log.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52510/discussion-between-alex-and-markus-malkusch)

Comment: In regards to: "This action now takes about 2 minutes, although the resource/semaphore with the same $iVarKey has been released about 10 seconds earlier.", could you possibly post the last dozen lines or so of an `strace` to be absolutely positive of which system call is causing the process to block?

Answer (score 3):

Your code assumes that the semaphore is always acquired, which may not be true. Try this

```
if(sem_acquire($this->rSemaphore)) {
    $mVar = shm_get_var($this->rShm,$iVarKey);
    if(!sem_release($this->rSemaphore)) {
      //log error
    }
}
else {
    //log error
}
```

One potential workaround is to use [flock()](http://www.php.net/flock) instead of the semaphore functions. The downside is that `flock()` is slower but depending on your use case it might be fast enough

```
$file = "/tmp/my_semaphore";
$fp = fopen($file,"r+");

if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { // wait/acquire lock
    shm_put_var($this->rShm, $iVarKey, $mVar);
    if(!flock($fp, LOCK_UN)) { //release file lock
      //log error
    }
}
else {
    //something went wrong, unable to attain lock
}
```

Comment: Why should an unsuccessful acquired semaphore block for two minutes?

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch an unsuccessful release might block the next acquire you need to check both

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have checked the return value of each `sem_release`, and each of them seem to have released the semaphore correctly. I could not find a single problem with `sem_release`. That said, an incorrect `sem_release` is not the cause of my problems.